# Closure compiler and including files

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

Is there a way to include files in a JavaScript file at "compile"-time in the source code? Basically what I'm looking for is a way to compile multiple files into one, without having to define the included files with the closure compile command.

As an example I'm using sass language to more precisely describe what I'm looking for;

```
# Sass file
# Include dimensions
@import "_dimensions.sass"
```

---

**Edit**

To clarify, comparably with the command;

`java -jar compiler.jar --js file1.js file2.js main.js --js_output_file compiled_output.js`

I was asking if there is a way to do these includes in code instead, so for example; If one file is called `main.js`, this file would itself include `file1.js` and `file2.js` by defining them in the source.

Comment: That answer would be huge, but should point to using a module system and a bundler.

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth That might actually answer my question. There is no way to "import" files with an in-source identifier by default?

Comment: By default meaning natively in a browser - no. However there is a large set of build tools to help you do this. I would start with [WebPack](https://webpack.js.org/).

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth No no, is that what my question sounds like? That's not what I mean. I mean like locally when the files are compiled and compressed, before it's even served to the end user. Example, instead of doing `java -jar compiler.jar --js file1.js file2.js file3.js  --js_output_file --js_output_file compiled_output.js` I was asking if `--js file1.js file2.js file3.js` could be defined in source.

Comment: Right. The answer is modules. https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Managing-Dependencies